# Скрипт обертывания элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужен скрипт, который обертывает в блок каждые два элемента определенного класса. Написал скрипт `$(".string_block:not(.row):lt(2)").wrapAll("<div class='row'></div>");` только он обертывает первые два. Кто знает как можно переделать, чтобы он обертывал каждые 2 элемента с классом .string_block

Сейчас так

```
<div class="reviews">
    <div class="string_block">1</div>
    <div class="string_block">2</div>
    <div class="string_block">3</div>
    <div class="string_block">4</div>
    <div class="string_block">5</div>
    <div class="string_block">6</div>
</div>
```

Нужно так

```
<div class="reviews">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="string_block">1</div>
       <div class="string_block">2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
       <div class="string_block">3</div>
       <div class="string_block">4</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
       <div class="string_block">5</div>
       <div class="string_block">6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Приведите пример разметки, а то не совсем понятно

Comment: @Arendach  обновил

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function wrapper(selector, count, wrapper) {
  // получаем все элементы по переданному селектору
  let elements = $(selector)

  // сгупированные элементы
  let groups = []

  // перебираем все элементы
  while (elements.length)
    // наполняем массив по count элементов
    groups.push(elements.splice(0, count))

  // перебираем все группы и оборачиваем
  for (group of groups)
    $(group).wrapAll(wrapper)
}

// первым параметром передаем селектор которые надо сгрупировать и обернуть
// второй параметр по сколько элементов будет в кажой групе
// третий параметр, то во что обворачиваем
wrapper('.block:not(.row)', 2, '<div class="row"></div>')
```

```css
.row {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block">1</div>
<div class="block">2</div>
<div class="block">3</div>
<div class="block">4</div>
<div class="block">5</div>
<div class="block">6</div>
<div class="block">7</div>
<div class="block">8</div>
<div class="block">9</div>
<div class="block">10</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
let $stringBlocks = $('.string_block');

for(let i = 0; i < $stringBlocks.length; i += 2) {
  $stringBlocks.slice(i, i + 2).wrapAll("<div class='row'></div>");
}
```

```css
.row{border:1px solid grey}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="reviews">
    <div class="string_block">string_block 1</div>
    <div class="string_block">string_block 2</div>
    <div class="string_block">string_block 3</div>
    <div class="string_block">string_block 4</div>
    <div class="string_block">string_block 5</div>
    <div class="string_block">string_block 6</div>
</div>
```